# ubuntu 16.04 install for oracle database 19c

Tags: oracle

[INS-35180] Unable to check for available memory.

Additional Information:
Exception details  - PRVG-1901 : failed to setup CVU remote execution framework directory "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu/" on nodes "ubuntu-psb133s01zfh"
Please select a different work area for the framework
An internal error occurred within cluster verification framework
The command executed was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu//exectask.sh -getver". The output from the command was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu/exectask: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

An internal error occurred within cluster verification framework
The command executed was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu//exectask.sh -getver". The output from the command was "/tmp/InstallActions2020-09-24_04-50-55AM/CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ubuntu/exectask: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "ubuntu-psb133s01zfh"

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: There are several branches of the linux family tree, with significant internal differences between them.  Oracle was not designed for the branch in which Ubuntu lives. Full. Stop.  Any instructions you find on the internet will just be hacks with no guarantee of success. And even if you do manage to get it installed, the fact that it is on a system for which it was not designed will make it likely you continue to run into problems.  Your best bet is to install Oracle Virtual Box on your Ubuntu machine, then create a VM that runs Oracle Linux.  That's what I did on my personal Ubuntu laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not a supported operating system for Oracle Database 19c.  Looking at the [list of supported operating systems for 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0), the only supported operating systems are Oracle Linux, RHEL, or SUSE.